# I want to send mail to my gmail but failed

Tags: php, xampp

my send.php code is

```
<?php
mail('mn###an@gmail.com', 'Mail Subject', 'From: md###an@gmail.com');

?>
```

and php.ini file is

[image]

[image]

and sendmail.php is

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24644436/6390490

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its best you use PHPMailer https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer . Its object oriented, and super easy with a lot of options .Here is a simple example
[image: Using phpmailer()]

Comment: I am doing a project on mysqli so would it be applicable?

Comment: Yes it would be. It doesn't require PDO or mysqli compatibility as it doesn't need a databse to function